# How to Use PowerShell Create a new Distribution List( Contact Group) on Outlook 2010 Contacts

Tags: powershell, outlook, distribution-list

I want to use PowerShell script to create a **new outlook Contact group** in contacts.

So far, I have something like this. What do I do next?

```
$outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application
$contacts = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(10)
$newcontact = $contacts.Items.Add()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that you want the DL list:

```
$dl= $contacts.Items.Add("IPM.DistList")
```

Comment: Are you having problems creating a DL or adding contacts to it?

Comment: Now I am able to create a DL, But I don't know how to add a contact to it

Comment: tried something like this $newcontact = $contacts.Items.Add()
$newcontact.FullName = "Jack"  $newcontact.Email("...@abc.com")
$newcontact.JobTitle = "Director"  $dl.AddMember($newcontact), but not working

Comment: See my reply to your other question.

Answer (score 0):

I found some help here; [Add an email to outlook distribution list using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680473/add-an-email-to-outlook-distribution-list-using-powershell)

If you scroll through that there are two chunks.  One if the list member is already an outlook contact and another if they are not.