# Add an email to outlook distribution list using powershell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, distribution-list, contactgroups

I just create a new distribution list on Outlook byt he following script

```
$outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application
$contacts = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(10)
$dl = $contacts.Items.Add("IPM.DistLIst")
$dl.DLName = "Group A"
$dl.Save()
```

and I Have an e-mail address  "manager@abc.com" with name to be "manager"

how do i use powershell to add this to the newly created distribution list?

I have to use powershell due to some reason, and I have tried this:

```
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Idneity "Group A" -Member "manager@abc.com"
```

But gives this error:

```
The term 'Add-DistributionGroupMember' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program.
```

Please help

[UPDATE]
Now I have a script that works:

```
  $outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application
  $contacts = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(10)
  $session = $outlook.Session
  $session.Logon("Outlook")
  $namespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  $recipient = $namespace.CreateRecipient("John Smith@abc.com")  # this has to be an exsiting contact
  $recipient.Resolve()  # check if this returns true
  $DL = $contacts.Items.Add("IPM.DistList")
  $DL.DLName = "test dl"
  $DL.AddMember($recipient)
  $DL.Save()
```

Comment: `Add-DistributionGroupMember` wont work because it is an Exchange cmdlet. You have a local group in your outlook. Presumably you would need to use `Outlook.Application` to edit it as well.  Do you want to add it when it is created or after the fact?

Comment: I want to add it after the fact. tried something like this: $dl.AddMember($newcontact)  where  $newcontact is newly created contact. but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddMember` only allows to pass a `Recipient` object as a parameter: call `Application.Session.CreateRecipient("manager@abc.com")` / `Recipient.Resolve` / `DistListItem.AddMember(Recipient).`

If you need to add a contact directly, you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDODistListItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDODistListItem.htm).`AddContact` method.

**UPDATE**: In Redemption, the following code adds a one-off member to a new DL list:

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Contacts = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
  set DL = Contacts.Items.Add("IPM.DistList")
  DL.DLName = "test dl"
  DL.AddMember("test@dimastr.com")
  DL.Save
```

Comment: I did this $r = $outlook.Session.CreateRecipient("manager@abc.com")
$r.Resolve
$dl.AddMember($r)
$dl.save()  it gives no error but the newly created list still contains nothing. Anything I did  wrong?

Comment: Do you call DIstListItem.Save?

Comment: tried something like this too : set $Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")/
$Session.Logon/
set $Contacts = Session.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderContacts)/
set $DL = Contacts.Items.Add("IPM.DistList")/
$DL.DLName = "Redemption test"/
$DL.AddMember("test <test@dimastr.com>")/
$DL.Save/

Comment: this gives an error Set-Variable : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null.

Comment: line 1: set $Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")

Comment: Did you actually install Redemption?

Comment: now I am getting this error: Exception calling "AddMember" with "1" argument(s): "Type mismatch. "               because of calling $dl.AddMember("test <test@dimastr.com>")

Comment: What is your latest code? I had no problem with the code in the (updated) answer above. I ran the script from OutlookSpy (click Script, paste the script, click Run).

Comment: Please check the updated question in the original post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As I already mentioned, if you are using the Outlook Object Model, DistListItem.AddMember only takes a Recipient object, which can be retrieved from Application.Session.CreateRecipient. If you are using Redemption (it must be installed of course), you can pass a string to RDODistLIstItem.AddMember.

Comment: I have updated the code in the OP, still has a little problem.

Comment: You need to call Recipient.Resolve and check that it returns true

Comment: I called  $recipient.Resolve() and it returns False, How should I fix this to be true?

Comment: You need to pass something that Outlook can actually resolve. Like an SMTP email address. Or a name that exists in the Outlook address book

Comment: The script works now, thank you so much for your help! =)

Comment: Please mark the answer as such if it answers your question.